# Get unique values out of a range

Tags: vba, excel, unique

So I am trying to create a function that will get all the unique values in a range, I'm new vba so I've made an attempt but it doesn't work (#VALUE). I eventually want each value in the array to be output one cell below it.

Here is the Code I wrote

```
Option Explicit

Function getUnique(dataSet As Range, Column As String)

Dim data() As String
Dim dataSize As Integer
Dim dictionary As Object
Dim i As Long

dataSize = dataSet.Rows.Count
Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


ReDim data(dataSize)
For i = 1 To UBound(data)
data(i) = dataSet(Column & i).Value
dictionary(data(i)) = 1
Next i

Dim v As Variant
For Each v In dictionary.Keys()

Debug.Print dictionary.Keys

Next v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can work with a few changes, as indicated here:

```
Function getUnique(dataSet As Range) '<<< remove Column

    Dim data() As String
    Dim dataSize As Integer
    Dim dictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long

    dataSize = dataSet.Rows.Count
    Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    ReDim data(dataSize)
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        data(i) = dataSet.Cells(i, 1).Value    '<<< using Cells
        dictionary(data(i)) = 1
    Next i

    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In dictionary.Keys()
        Debug.Print v    '<<< 
    Next v
End Function
```

---

If, though, you are attempting to use this Function in a Worksheet cell then it won't work if you attempt to put values into other cells. User-Defined Functions don't work like that and you'll have to make it a Sub and run it on clicking a button, or some other event.

Comment: I am only putting in a range of cells like (M1:M14, "A") why is the column an integer?
Holy snap it works but even if i put 95 or 30 in the column section it doesn't change anything?

Comment: Oh right, I wondered what you were doing. I switched it to an Integer. You can switch it back if you like. But, as I say, the use of Column seems redundant: the dataSet already includes the column. I'm not sure why you are supplying column "A".

Comment: how do i get rid of it then, what does it do on line 10 of what you wrote?

Comment: You can get rid of it and use `Cells(i, 1)` in my code to loop down the (only) column of the supplied range.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to not have it as well? I got it working but I don't want possible future viewers to be confused by it.

Comment: Okay, I've removed Column. It is nice to hear the consideration for other readers. Yes, Cells(3,1) is the third row, first column, of the range.